# Problemas con instalar angular cli

Tags: angularjs, nodejs, angular-cli

al intentar instalar el angular cli usando sudo npm i @angular/cli

me sale este error

```
npm WARN saveError ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Luis/package.json'
npm notice created a lockfile as package-lock.json. You should commit this file.
npm WARN enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/Luis/package.json'
npm WARN Luis No description
npm WARN Luis No repository field.
npm WARN Luis No README data
npm WARN Luis No license field.
```

Comment: **Importante** No es recomendable instalar paquetes con sudo, y si quieres instalarlo de manera globlal debes incluir el parámetro `-g`, de esta forma `npm i -g @angular/cli`

Answer (score 1):

En este caso tienes que estar en el Path, donde esta tú proyecto y ejecutar:

**npm init**

Para inicializar el proyecto y crear el archivo **package.json** en el carpeta del proyecto.

Una vez realizado deberá funcionar la instalación de la dependencia con:

**npm install @angular/cli --save**

Tal y como indica en la documentación de Angular-cli:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#installation

Por cierto la esta pregunta ya esta duplicada en:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45531633/npm-warn-enoent-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-open-c-users-nuwanst-packag